# phpmyadmin #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server. after installing mysql command line client

Tags: mysql, command-line, phpmyadmin

I installed wamp.phpmyadmin working fine. Now that I have installed mysql command line client I am not able to connect to my databases from mysql command line or phpmyadmin.  After restarting I could not access phpmyadmin `#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server`.  In addition to that my mysql command line not accepting my password and rejects my config files:

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24
```

**my.ini**

```
port=3306
```

**my config.inc.php**

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'whtevr';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

**httpd.conf**

```
listen port:80
```

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0

**my.ini**

```
port:3306
```

Again, I reinstalled mysql command line with port changed to 3307

```
port:3307
```

WAMP works fine accessing all the databases but from mysql command line client I could not access all my databases.  It is only showing `show databases;`

```
information_schema 
mysql 
test
```

Comment: Try changing the host to "127.0.0.1" Also, did you install the MySQL server again? If you did it might have changed your roots passwords. Try to reset it, you should find how online.

Comment: yes i have installed sql server again with port 3307.and please can u detailed your answer.

Comment: @black, if it's not a bother for you, do yo think you could set my answer as the accepted one? It seems it's the one it has worked the most.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In case MySQL Server is up but you are still getting the error:

For anyone who still have this issue,
I followed awesome tutorial http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-9-mavericks/

However i still got #1045 error. 
What really did the trick was to change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` at your `config.inc.php`. Why was it failing if locahost points to 127.0.0.1? I don't know. But it worked.

===== EDIT =====

Long story short, it is because of permissions in mysql. It may be set to accept connections from 127.0.0.1 but not from localhost.

The actual answer for why this isn't responding is here:
https://serverfault.com/a/297310

Comment: Changing mine to 127.0.0.1 was all I needed, as well. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be helpful budy!

Comment: Wow. That tutorial sure isn't awesome anymore. Bad information, telling you to do things and follow links that don't exist anymore. That's why on SO you're supposed to *give* answers, not *link to* answers. Also changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 made no difference to me.

Answer (score 7):

I was experiencing the same problem on OS X. I've solved it now. I post my solution here for anyone who has the similar issue.

Firstly, I set the password for root in `mysql` client:

```
shell> mysql -u root
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MY_PASSWORD');
```

Then, I checked the version info:

```
shell> /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p version
...
Server version    5.6.26
Protocol version  10
Connection        Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket       /tmp/mysql.sock
Uptime:           11 min 0 sec
...
```

Finally, I changed the `connect_type` parameter from `tcp` to `socket` and added the parameter `socket` in `config.inc.php`:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'socket';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/tmp/mysql.sock';
```

Comment: Separating the host and socket worked for me thanks! Previously I had 
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:/tmp/mysql5.sock';`
which works for vanilla php/mysql but didn't work here for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: Nope. `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PASSWORD('MY_PASSWORD')' at line 1`

Answer (score 2):

If you reinstalled the server it means that that the new installation most likely overwrote your username and passwords. (You might want to try loggin without a password see if it works).

If it is a clean install you need to [set the root password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/default-privileges.html) .

Otherwise, you will [need to reset root permissions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html).

Comment: Downvoted. After the night I've had, I'm not even bothering to click those links. Please give *answers* on SO, not *links to answers*.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error. It worked normally after I clean up the cookies.

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks for sharing!!

Answer (score 1):

Go to phpMyAdmin Directory of your Localhost Software Like Xampp, Mamp or others. Then change the host from **localhost** to **127.0.0.1** and change the port to **3307** . After that go to your data directory and delete all error log files except **ibdata1** which is important file to hold your created database table link. Finaly restart mysql.I think your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this error for myself, but it was a bit silly on my part. Still worth checking if the above doesn't help you.

In my case, I was editing the config files in `/etc/phpmyadmin`, my install was located in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`, and my install was not actually opening the `/etc/phpmyadmin` config files, as I thought it would. So I just did this command:

`ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/conf* /usr/share/phpmyadmin`

For those not in the know, `ln -s` makes a soft link (basically a shortcut). So that command just makes shortcuts from the config files in `/etc` to the `/usr/share` install.

By the way, I figured this out after using the program `opensnoop`, which shows you what files are being opened (technically, traces `open()` syscalls and the pid of the process, as they happen), which you can install on Ubuntu with `apt-get install perf-tools-unstable`, or you can get it [here.](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/opensnoop)

Comment: `ln: /usr/share/phpmyadmin: Operation not permitted`. And, yes, I used sudo.

Answer (score 1):

After like three (3) hours of google..ing.This is the solution to the problem:
First, I run this command;

`$mysqladmin -u root -p[your root password here] version`
Which outputs:

```
    Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

    Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
    affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
    owners.

    Server version      5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
    Protocol version    10
    Connection      Localhost via UNIX socket
    UNIX socket     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    Uptime:         1 hour 54 min 3 sec
```

Finally, I changed the `connect_type` parameter from `tcp` to `socket` and added the parameter `socket` in `config.inc.php`:

```
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'socket';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock';
```

All credit goes to this person:
[This is the correct solution](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1227057/micmia)

Answer (score 1):

You have to go into your mySQL settings and change the settings to Legacy authentication. I use mysql community installer and it allows you to go back and reconfigure the settings.
Create a new user, and choose standard authentication, choose a password, thats it.
Its that simple!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since the username and password is added in `config.inc.php`, you need to change:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';`

TO:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';`

And save the file.

You will then need to **restart WAMP** after making the above changes.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error once, but only with one specific user. So what I did is remove the user and re-create it with the same name and password.

Then after I re-imported the database, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 3 things:

1. First try clearing browser's cache
2. Try to assign username & password statically into config.inc.php
3. Once you've done with installation, delete the config.inc.php file under "phpmyadmin" folder

**The last one worked for me.**

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following $cfg helps to narrow down the problem

```
$cfg['Error_Handler']['display'] = true;
$cfg['Error_Handler']['gather'] = true;
```

**Don't forget** to remove those $cfg after done debugging!

Answer (score 0):

Every once in a while, and this isn't often, but every once in a while, there's a typo in your password.  A subtle difference between an upper and lower case letter, for example. I went through many, many of these solutions.

I had simply mistyped the password, and it was saved to my browser, so I didn't think to check it again.

Since this error CAN be caused by a missed password, just double-check before you go on this quest.

Answer (score -1):

Before you start, **go to the directory "phpMyAdmin"** preferably the one **in your localhost**, clear all of your cookies, and have your sql running by entering:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

To fix the error , you will have to run the following commands in your terminal:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

then:

```
mysql -u root
```

after which, you'll need to change your permissions inside the mySQL shell:

```
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;
```

Refresh your phpMyAdmin window, re-enter the "root" username (or whichever is applicable), and your password and you should be good to go. 
Check http://machiine.com/2013/how-to-setup-phpmyadmin-on-a-mac-with-osx-10-8-mamp-part-3/ if you are willing to set up from scratch.